# SmartWatch 2 app without Smart Connect

Tags: android, android-studio, sony-smartwatch

I have a Sony Smartwatch 2 and I am currently trying to develop an app for it on Android Studio, but I am facing a difficulty:

I want the user to be able to choose if he wants or not to use the smartwatch option, that means I dont want to have my app started only by the "Smart Connect" app. I would like to Launch my app as a normal app and, once the app is running, give the user the possibility of using the Smartwatch.

If I use one of Sony's sample projects as a base to my app, it automatically gets installed on "Smart Connect". By trying to add the Smart Extension Utils and Smart Extension API to my "common" app, I can't get it to work with the smartwatch 2.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you can still have your app launch as a normal app by creating a main activity and setting it in your manifest as the default launcher.

So for instance create your java class:

```
com.yourapp.package/MainActivity
```

Then update your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: you were so helpful answering this question, maybe you could also help me with my next one... Thank you very much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082148/control-app-sony-smartwatch2 @Robert-Sony